# Picketlink Defaultlogincredentials no body writer on Rest service

Tags: rest, java-ee-7, apache-tomee, picketlink

I'm following the Picketlink quickstart guide.

I've created a login Rest sevice on Tomee 1.7 for users.
It Consumes the contentType that is provided by the quickstart guide. (application/x-authc-username-password+json)
It takes the Picketlink Defaultlogincredentials object as a parameter.

When I pass in the json object from the UI I get the followong error;
No message body writer has been found for response class Defaultlogincredentials.

I've also tried setting the contentType to application/json.

The Rest service doesn't know how to parse the content into the object.

I've looked through the pom.xml and the quickstart project to see if I missed a dependency or a config setting.
The difference is that the quickstart runs on jboss and I'm trying on tomee.

How do I get the Rest service on Tomee to parse the content into the Defaultlogincredentials object?